# Configuring routes in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, configure

HI,

I have created a custom index page for my application , which has two image links , one for users and other for admin. How shall I configure the routes in the routes.rb, so that the links take to the dedicated pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be create condition in the template:

```
<% if @currentUser.isAdmin %>
....
# image link one
....

<% else %>
....
# image link two
....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have two controllers, say Admins and Users, you could say in your routes

```
resources :admins
resources :users
```

and in your index view write something like

```
<%= link_to 'admins', admins_path %>
<%= link_to 'users', users_path %>
```

for more about routing and rails in general please read the rails guides available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)